# Why exclude the first entropy bonus term in the soft Q-function in SAC?

Tags: soft-actor-critic, entropy

Based on [OpenAI Spinning Up](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html) description of Soft Actor Critic (SAC) the soft Q-function is defined as

[image]

and as they say

> Q value is changed to include the entropy bonuses from every timestep except the first.

I feel like it should make sense somehow, but they do not give any further explanation, and I don't see why it is correct. Especially because in the soft value function the first bonus term is also used:
[image]

Could someone please explain this?